# How to toggle the button backcolor based on selection - Javascript - Semantic UI

Tags: javascript

I have a section of my web page as below

```
<div class="ui divided list">
 <div class="item">
            <div class="ui segment">
                <h4 class="ui left">Payment method</h4>
                <div class="ui right buttons">
                    <div class="ui button" ng-bind="item.payment.option1">{{item.payment.option1}}</div>
                    <div class="or"></div>
                    <div class="ui button" item.payment.option2>{{item.payment.option2}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I get the output 'similar' to the pattern here. But I have not included 'positive' class to the ui button like

```
<div class="ui positive button">
```

Because, I dont want any option to be defautly selected. But I want to toggle the colors according to the clicks. Can someone tell me where I can make change?

Answer (score 1):

In your css do something like

```
.button {
   background: silver;
}

.positive {
    background: green;
}
```

So when the new class positive, gets added, it will then take the css background for `.positive` instead of `.button`.

Comment: Ya ..I can do that. But my doubt is , I should not show a button as positive or negative. when it loads. Also, the button I click should become positive. "I DONT HAVE ANY STANDARD POSITIVE BUTTON" Please let me know further from here.